# Delete with select mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to delete rows using delete and select mysql

I use this rows not work :

```
delete from items T1 where T1.base_item = 
(SELECT T2.type,T2.id From furniture T2 where T2.type = 'i' );
```

Comment: What error do you get from de database?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T1 where T1.base_item = (SELECT T2.type,T2.id From furniture T2 where T2.type = ' at line 1

Answer (score 3):

This does not work because `=` expects a single value while the subselect returns a result set.

There are two approaches you can take, you can use an `IN()` clause or your can delete across a join.

The first would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM items
WHERE base_item IN (SELECT id FROM furniture WHERE type = 'i')
```

Note that only a single field should be specified in the subselect.  I am assuming that `furniture.id` relates to `items.base_item` in this case.  If `furniture.type` is really the matching field, use that in the subselect instead.

The second approach would look like this:

```
DELETE items
FROM items INNER JOIN furniture
  ON items.base_item = furniture.id
WHERE furniture.type = 'i'
```

Again my assumption here is that `items.base_item` relates to `furniture.id`.

Which is better to use (assuming all applicable fields are indexed) would likely depend on the number of rows expected in each table and the cardinality of your data.  You might want to test yourself to see which is more efficient for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Your `SELECT` statement is returning a set (or records) with two columns. You need to use `IN` (not `=`) and only `SELECT` a single column

```
delete from items T1 where T1.base_item in (
   SELECT T2.id From furniture T2 where T2.type = 'i' 
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?  You can use a join to delete the items you want

```
DELETE T1
FROM items T1 
INNER JOIN furniture T2 ON T1.base_item = T2.id
WHERE T2.type = 'i'
```